# XSL to XML - How do i do this?

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my xml file:

```
<HarperCollins>
    <BookComingSoon>
        <BookDescription>
        After a family tragedy...
            <NewParagraph/>
        Holden Cameron was addicted...
            <NewParagraph/>
        When equipment, treasure...
        </BookDescription>
    <BookComingSoon>
</HarperCollins>
```

and I must change it with XML to look like this(the BookDescription part):

```
<blurb>
    <p>
     Example text example text example text, woo!
    </p>
    <p>
     More example text. Amazing!
    </p>
</blurb>
```

how do i do this with XSL(1.0)?

this is what i got so far:

```
<blurb>
   <xsl:for-each select="BookDescription">
       <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
   </xsl:for-each>
</blurb>
```

**EDIT**

this is the full xml doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<HarperCollins>
    <BookComingSoon>
        <Book>Night Diver</Book>
        <By>Elizabeth Lowell</By>
        <Pages>368</Pages>
        <CoverImage>nd-el.jpg</CoverImage>
        <OnSale>4/8/2014</OnSale>
        <ForFansOf>Romance</ForFansOf>
        <ForFansOf>Suspense</ForFansOf>
        <BookDescription>
        After a family tragedy... 
            <NewParagraph/>
        Holden Cameron...
            <NewParagraph/>
        When equipment, treasure...
        </BookDescription>
    </BookComingSoon>
    <BookComingSoon>
        <Book>Under a Silent Moon</Book>
        <By>Elizabeth Haynes</By>
        <Pages>352</Pages>
        <CoverImage>uasm-eh.jpg</CoverImage>
        <OnSale>4/15/2014</OnSale>
        <ForFansOf>Suspense</ForFansOf>
        <ForFansOf>Thriller</ForFansOf>
        <BookDescription>
        In the crisp, ...
            <NewParagraph />
        As DCI Louisa Smith ...
        </BookDescription>
    </BookComingSoon>
</HarperCollins>
```

The for-each I use is to do both the  nodes.

Comment: What code have you tried? Seems like that would be the first place to start.

Comment: <blurb>
 <xsl:for-each select="BookDescription">
      <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
 </xsl:for-each>
</blurb>

Comment: You should really add an entire example of your XSLT. We have no idea what the context is for the `xsl:for-each`. We might've been able to guess if you also added what your current output is, but the full XSLT is better. If you're actually getting results from that `xsl:for-each` (context is `BookComingSoon`), try adding `text()` to the end of the select (`select="BookDescription/text()"`).

Comment: If your book descriptions contains addtional markup you may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236056/xslt-reading-content-that-is-devided-by-empty-tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could go simpler. You can avoid the empty template by never matching the NewParagraph element in the first place.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <blurb><xsl:apply-templates match="//BookDescription/text()" /></blurb>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="BookDescription/text()">
   <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

For-each is totally overused :-)
Try this:

```
   <xsl:template match="BookComingSoon">
      <blurb><xsl:apply-templates match="BookDescription" /></blurb>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="BookDescription/text()">
      <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="NewParagraph" />
```

The first one will kick the processing of the book description. The second pulls out all the text and surrounds it with <p>, and the last suppresses the unneeded element.